# integrate jenkins with docker-compose.yml file for laravel project

Tags: laravel, docker, jenkins, docker-compose

below my docker-compose.yml file :

```
version: '2'
services:
  webserver:
    build: .
    ports:
     - '85:80'
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www/html
      - ./apache.conf:/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf
    depends_on:
      - db
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    volumes:
      - "./.data/db:/var/lib/mysql"
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_DATABASE: laravel_db
      MYSQL_USER: laravel
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: laravel
    ports:
      -  3307:3306
  phpmyadmin:
    image: nazarpc/phpmyadmin
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
    ports:
      - '88:80'
    depends_on:
      - db
```

i have php project and i have orchestrated all my images like apache , mysql and phpmyadmin to run my project with docker.

Actually, i want to orchestrate jenkins inside my docker-compose.yml file and i don't find any way to do that

there is some one can help me.

Comment: Do you mean you want to start jenkins in the same compose file?

Comment: yes exactly that's what i want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Integrating jenkins in the above compose file is as simple as adding the below service:

```
  jenkins:
    image: jenkins/jenkins
    container_name: jenkins
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
      - "50000:50000"
```

When you add the above and run `docker-compose up`, jenkins will be started and will be accessible on `http://localhost:8080`

Comment: it work perfectly for me. i just run this : docker logs containerId to find jenkins password for admin